# Next to 1st page works, 2nd page doesn't

Tags: android

Because my 1st page and 2nd page OnClick have the same thing going on and i tried to copy and paste, but it doesn't work. Whenever the 2nd page Onclick to the next page, it crashes. What should i do?

1st page - hira1_1 > hira1_2 > hira1_3 working well

```
package com.linguido;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class bc_hira1_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bc_hira1_1);
    }

    public void toHira1_2(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, bc_hira1_2.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

---

```
package com.linguido;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class bc_hira1_2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bc_hira1_2);
    }

    public void toHira1_3(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, bc_hira1_3.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

2nd page - hira2_1 > hira2_2 > hira2_3 crashes at hira2_1 > hira2_2

```
package com.linguido;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class bc_hira2_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bc_hira2_1);
    }

    public void toHira2_2(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, bc_hira2_2.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

---

```
package com.linguido;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class bc_hira2_2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bc_hira2_2);
    }

    public void toHira2_3(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, bc_hira2_3.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Add your activity in Manifest file.

Comment: @SatanPandeya OH YEA, i totally forgot about that. Thanks :)